# Getting the correct data back from a subquery, SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the number of instructors in my database that are capable of teaching the courses that have been taught by an instructor named "Ian Goldman".

Here are the schemas for the relations involved:

[image]
[image]

```
/*Instructors that can teach the courses that have been taught by Ian Goldman*/
select 
    InstructorNo
from 
    AreasOfCourse, AreasOfInstructor, 
    (/*courses that have been taught be Ian Goldman*/
     select DISTINCT CourseNo
     from CourseSections
     where InstructorNo = (select InstructorNO
                           from Instructors
                           where FirstName = 'Ian' 
                             and LastName = 'Goldman')
    ) AS GoldmansCourses
where 
    AreasofCourse.CourseNo = GoldmansCourses.CourseNo 
    and AreasofInstructor.AreaName = AreasOfCourse.AreaName
group by 
    InstructorNo
having 
    COUNT(DISTINCT AreasofCourse.CourseNo) = COUNT((GoldmansCourses.CourseNo)
```

The `GoldmansCourses` subquery returns a relation with 2 distinct courses when I query the database (i.e. the courses that Goldman has taught). When I call `COUNT((GoldmansCourses.CourseNo))` on the last line, I'm expecting to get 2 back.

However, what actually happens is that I'm given the number of tuples in each grouping (i.e. the query gives me information on the Cartesian Product in the from clause rather than the number of courses in the `GoldmansCourses` relation).

How can I fix this? I need access to the original subquery  `GoldmansCourses`, not the column in the cartesian product computed by the `FROM` clause.

Comment: A sample of current and desire output will help a lot.

Comment: And you need to provide a more complete schema. You need create a JOIN between the tables but without field name we will be guessing

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT InstructorNo
 FROM AreasOfInstructor AI
 JOIN AreasOfCourse  AC
   ON AI.Course = AC.Course
 LEFT JOIN GoldmansCourses GC
   ON AI.Course = GC.Course
 WHERE 
     GC.Course IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY InstructorNo
 HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT AreasofCourse.CourseNo) = COUNT((GoldmansCourses.CourseNo)
```

Comment: I added the data you requested. I do the join using the WHERE clause. I'll posted expected/actual results in a minute

Comment: What I'd like to know is how to get at the results of the `GoldmansCourses` subquery before it is involved in the CartesianProduct in the `FROM` clause. Everything else is working as I expected

Comment: I thought of trying to name the entire relation produced by the subclaus, but I can't seem to get the syntax right